# How can I run `calendar-redraw` automatically end of each day?

Tags: calendar

I keep `calender` remain open. End of the day `calendar-today` does not update itself, hance I have to run manually `calendar-redraw` usually I forget to run it.

End of each day or hourly if `calendar` is opened can `calendar-redraw` automicatically run with a help of a timer or some other approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need `midnight-mode`:

> To use the file, put `(require 'midnight)` into your `.emacs`.  Then, at midnight, Emacs will run the normal hook `midnight-hook`.  You can put whatever you like there, say, `calendar`;

This might be helpful (I haven't tested it yet because it's not midnight here):

```lisp
(setq midnight-hook (list (lambda ()
                            (with-current-buffer "*Calendar*"
                              (calendar-redraw)))))
```

---

To summarize, add the following code to your Emacs configuration file:

```lisp
(require 'midnight)
(midnight-mode)
(setq midnight-hook (list
                     (lambda ()
                       (require 'calendar)
                       (when (get-buffer calendar-buffer)
                         (with-current-buffer calendar-buffer
                           (calendar-redraw))))))
```

Comment: Does this  run only if calendar is running?

Comment: @alper: Enable `midnight-mode` and then it will run the functions stored in `midnight-hook`.  If you want it to run only when `calendar` is running, just put a condition check into the lambda expression, e.g., `(when (get-buffer "*Calendar*") ...)`

Comment: Should I put `(when (get-buffer "*Calendar*")` before or after `(with-current-buffer "*Calendar*"`?

Comment: @alper: Please see my updated answer.